# Read content of external script tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

A common pattern for loading backbone templates is something like:

```
<script type='text/template' id='foo'>
    my template
</script>

----
var whatever = $('#foo').html();
```

I would like to include the script in an external file like so:

```
<script type='text/template' id='foo' src='myTemplate.tpl'></script>
```

But the `html()` of `foo` is now empty.

I watched the browser pull the template file down, but I am not sure if it is in the page dom or not. Is there a simple way to reference the content of the script in javascript, or did the browser simply ignore it and throw out the result?

Comment: have you tried doing it on document.ready?

Comment: Yes, everything is running well after document.ready

Comment: From an optimization standpoint your page will load faster if the templates are inline, or are declared as javascript variables.  Loading every external resource on your page will incur HTTP overhead.  You should at least use `defer` or `async` on them so that the browser knows it can load them along with everything else and doesn't have to block

Comment: Have you tried it without jQuery? I'd suppose `document.getElementById("foo").textContent`

Comment: You didn't ran into a silent security error? Cross-domain- (or localhost-)requests don't allow you to get the content, they might return an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to actually execute externally loaded script you have to do an eval() of the contents. You're not adding it to the DOM really since it's script, you're adding it to the JS runtime. There might be other ways of doing it but eval() is generally considered a security hole since malicious code could be evaluated.

What I tend to do is generate template sections on the server so I know all my JS is there when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I am thinking I may need to go this route, and just have the server spew the file contents inline.

Comment: Just be careful if your templates have minified code in them. Be aware of how the backend renders the HTML/JS. I've had some funky issues with how different backends interpret whitespace and linebreaks during regurgitation. Just a warning in case you start getting baffled by strange errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the point is execute an action just after the script has been loaded you can put a `onload` attribute on the script tag. If you want to download the content in runtime, then you could use the async download strategy (like Gats pointed).

It´s important keep in mind some important points when using templates for jquery templates in external files, there is an interesting [article](http://encosia.com/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/) about jquery templates with external files, you must check it.